# What should spl_autoload_register callable $autoload_function return for class_exists()

Tags: php, class, autoload

PHP manual on [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is not complete about what should  `callable $autoload_function` return so `class_exists()` can work properly.

```
class_exists('cl_name', true);     // autoload
class_exists('cl_name', false)     // don't call autoload
```

Right now I am returning TRUE on success and FALSE if class is not found from autoload f. It seems to fix the problem, but I would like some confirmation that this is the real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$autoload_function` return nothing (void, null).

`class_exists` with the `$autoload` argument to `true` does not rely on what value returns the autoloader. What the autoloaders do is to include the class, if there was. So that multiple autoloaders may have the opportunity to load the class properly.

Comment: so, class_exists() will work properly regardless of what autoload() returns? AND if multiple autoloaders don't include for ex. class.php file, class_exists fill return false.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is the work of `class_exists` to checks if the class has been defined. Considers that the class could also have been already loaded earlier, so `class_exists` can really don't rely on what' the return value of an autoloader.

Comment: this is a guess how class_exists works: Check for class in "PHP namespaces", if no class, and use autoload, start all autoload f(), check for class in "autoloaded namespaces" again.

Comment: Yes. Internally PHP know which classes were defined. The autoloaders are just the last chance to load the class before PHP fails with an error.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `$autoload_function` doesn't matter. If you check for `class_exists('cl_name', false);` there's no attempt to autoload the class, so your `$autoload_function` won't even be called.

Comment: I am aware of that, as it was written in my question. I am interested in case when autoload is true.